# Java Logger prefixes each message?

Tags: java, eclipse, logging

I'm using a Logger for debugging in Eclipse.  I've created a logger with `Logger.getAnonymousLogger()` and am calling it by using `logger.log("Something")`.  In eclipse, this is the console:

```
Aug 13, 2014 12:04:47 AM com.tips48.flame.utilities.Logger log
INFO: [00:04:47.163][Debug] Something
```

I'd like to get rid of the first line.  I'm not sure if it's an Eclipse feature or Java feature, but I've never encountered it before.  `System.out.println` works fine, but I'd like to use the Java logger.

Comment: Configure your `java.util.logging`. Tutorial [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/configuration.html).

Comment: It's probably a console logger in the root logger.  Replace it with one that does what you want.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen What am I configuring? That's what I'm confused about. And @markspace Use `Logger.getLogger("MyLogger");`?

Comment: You need to configure your log format. Most likely, the default is using [SimpleFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html) which can be configured by setting the `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format` property as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format).

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature of the [SimpleFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html)
class. You can replace the formatter in the default handler which will be found in the root logger that you can customize to format your log messages how ever you want.

Java Loggers form a tree which all end at the root logger. Each logger can have zero or more Handlers which are responsible for outputting the log messages in some format. All builtin Handlers use a formatter to format each log message before outputting it. The root logger usually contains a default Handler that prints to stdout/stderr and uses a SimpleFormatter object as it's formatter. You can disable the use of the default handler, replace it's formatter, or disable the use of parent Loggers to stop output to console.